# Can a 6V rechargeable battery be charged to 5V after complete discharge?

Tags: battery-charging, raspberry-pi

I live in a area where there is power cut. I have to power a Raspberry Pi (a device rated as 5V and 300-700mA) through micro USB continuously. So I decided to make my own mini inverter.

Now I have a 5V-2A DC adapter and a 6V-4.5Ah rechargeable battery. The battery is discharged and can only supply 2-3V now. So can it be charged to 5V using the 5V DC adapter?

Also please take a look at the circuit I am using for my inverter. Please tell me what possible resistances should I use and at what places?

[image]

Comment: What chemistry is the battery?

Comment: It's lead-acid type

Answer (score 2):

No. As tomnexus has pointed out you need a voltage higher than that of the battery before it will charge properly.

An inverter is a circuit to convert DC to AC. These are most common in small UPS power supplies where a 12 V battery powers a circuit to convert to AC and step up the voltage using a transformer.

The circuit you have sketched is not an inverter but is a crude DC UPS. There are a couple of problems:

- The diodes drop 0.6 to 0.7 V so the most you can possibly get out of your circuit will be 4.3 V.
- You have the same problem with the 5 V rechargeable battery. You can only get 4.3 V at the battery and if it held any usable charge you would lose another 0.7 V on the way from D to C dropping you to 3.6 V.

Your best bet would be to use a 12 V battery (an old car battery would work and even if not much use for a car would run a Pi for a long time) and a car battery charger. Then use a 12 V to 5 V converter to power the Pi.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhgHYQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Charge the battery while power is available. The Pi can run off the battery while it is charging. You could use a car cigarette lighter to USB adapter to power the Pi or use a voltage regulator, as shown. (If you're using the regulator you need to add some capacitors to the input and output terminals to prevent oscillation. There are lots of examples of this on the web.)

Comment: Just one more question. How will the current be regulated? Would the device draw as much current as it needs?

Comment: The type of charger depends on the battery chemistry and you haven't told us that. Add it to to the question (not to the comments). i.e., Lead-acid, Li-Ion, NiCd, NiMn, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a sealed lead acid battery? If so, you are out of luck, sorry.

First, a nominal 6 V battery should read (with no load) 6.3 V fully charged, 6.0 V empty. If it's been discharged to only 3 V, or 1 V / cell, for more than a few hours, then it's probably unrecoverable.

Second, to charge a battery you have to respect the internal chemistry - it's not like a capacitor which can be charged only part of the way. To charge a 6 V lead acid battery requires 6.9 to 7.1 V. 5 V will just not work.

So you have a good idea but will need a new battery and another power supply.

Comment: So if I get a new battery and a 12V DC adapter what should the new connections look like, I.e what resistances needs to be added?